# AngularJS / Browserify/ Gulp: external controller not running

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I have the following set up within my `app.js` file:

```
require('angular');
require('angular-ui-router');

var storelistingCtrl = require('./controllers/storeListingsCtrl');

var ngApp = angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router'], function($interpolateProvider){
        //-- as the output conflicts with blade lets alter the defaults
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[['); 
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    })
    .config(['$stateProvider','$logProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $logProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

        $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);    
    }])

//-- controllers
ngApp.controllers('storelistingCtrl', ['$scope', storelistingCtrl]);
```

And with in my `storelistingCtrl.js` file i just have a simple output to test:

```
module.exports = function($scope) {
    console.log('loaded');
};
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
    Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.18/ng/areq?p0=storelistingCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    .....
```

Am i missing something?

UPDATE

See my answer,  Always sort it once i posted on here.

Comment: It looks like your `require` for your controller is not finding anything. Can you double check that `./controllers/storeListingsCtrl` is the correct relative path to the controller? I noticed the different case for `Listing` in the module name, whereas in the variable name you used lowercase... That alone doesn't mean anything, but you might have a typo.

Comment: Thats what i thought at first but if i init at the require stage require('./controllers/storeListingsCtrl')()  then i get the 'loaded' outputted to the console, so it seems to have run it??

Comment: Not really... because then you're calling the function yourself, not angular.

Comment: @gtramontina thanks you made me look closely though where i discovered the error(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular controller is spelt wrong it should be:

```
   ngApp.controller('storelistingCtrl...
```

and not `controllers`..

Also the controller name is case sensitive so it needs a capital 'L' for Listing...

```
     ngApp.controller('storelistingsCtrl...
```

becomes

```
     ngApp.controller('storeListingCtrl...
```